# Finding columns that are NOT NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

I had an assignment for each table to count nullable columns. Easy:

```
 SELECT table_name, count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE is_nullable='NO'
 GROUP BY table_name;
```

Now I have to modify this to count "columns that have property "NOT NULL"". Will the following code do this or will it just check weather column name is not null?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE A AS 
SELECT DISTINCT column_name, table_name AS name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY table_name, column_name;

SELECT name, count(*) FROM A
GROUP BY name;
```

If no... Any advices?

Comment: I think the question is getting at whether or not the column was set NOT NULL explicitly or if it is a primary key (which can never be null). If so, it does not look like COLUMNS has that info. May have to search through the column def in pg_attrdef for NOT NULL. Otherwise, it is just restating your first query.

Comment: It looks like COLUMNS has that information to me. Declaring a column either `NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` or simply `PRIMARY KEY` sets is_nullable to 'NO'. Columns explicitly declared NULL and implicitly declared NULL sets is_nullable to 'YES'.

Answer (score 75):

No.

This query

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name, table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
```

will return all the rows that have a value in the column "column_name".

All rows in that table will always have a value in the column "column_name".

Do you just need to know how many columns are nullable and how many are non-nullable?

```
SELECT is_nullable, COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY is_nullable;
```

Count by table name? I think you can use this.

```
SELECT table_name, is_nullable, count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY table_name, is_nullable
ORDER BY table_name, is_nullable;
```

Comment: For those googlers who were looking to list all columns with a `NOT NULL` constraint: 

`SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND is_nullable = 'NO';`.

Change `table_schema = 'public'` as needed.

Answer (score 3):

To get a count of all NOT NULL columns:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE  table_name  = 'table_name'
     AND is_nullable = 'NO';
```

Comment: please add a bit of comments to your answer

Answer (score 2):

To get a count of all NOT NULL columns in any table, use:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'table_schema_here'
   AND table_name   = 'table_name_here'
   AND is_nullable = 'YES';
```

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: `is_nullable = 'YES'`?